# In MySQL, can I create an index on a TIMESTAMP function

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with millions of rows, including one DATE and one TIME columns.

Changing the table structure is not an option, though adding a new index will be possible.

Considering this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE TIMESTAMP(Date, Time) BETWEEN 'X' AND 'Y';
```

I have indexes on the date and time columns, also an index on the date AND time columns, yet when I use the TIMESTAMP function, the query uses no indexes.

Question is, can I make an index which uses the TIMESTAMP function (not data type). If not, is there a way I can change the query above to use indexes?

I am trying to keep the query nice and short, and attempting to avoid having to iterate over each date if possible.

**EDIT:**

So, since MySQL does not support expression indexes, is there a way I can change this query to use either the date or the (date, time) indexes?

Comment: Are you allowed to do the reverse (convert the constant timestamps to (date,time) combinations? `WHERE (Date, Time) >= (Xdate, Xtime) AND (Date, Time) <= (Ydate, Ytime)`

Comment: @ypercube, with respect to the index search, I don't think that expression has any benefit over the `Date BETWEEN` example I gave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called *expression indexes*, but not all RDBMS brands support this.

You can't do this in MySQL.

The closest thing is [persistent virtual columns](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/virtual-columns/), which is supported in a fork of MySQL called MariaDB.  But if you can't change your schema, I suppose switching to another RDBMS package is also out of the question.

PostgreSQL is an example of an RDBMS that [does support expression indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-expressional.html).

---

As a workaround, I'd recommend filtering just on your Date column, which should narrow down the search significantly if you have an index on that column.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN 'Xdate' AND 'Ydate' 
  AND CASE WHEN Date = 'Xdate' THEN TIMESTAMP(Date, Time) >= 'X' 
           WHEN Date = 'Ydate' THEN TIMESTAMP(Date, Time) <= 'Y'
           ELSE 1 END;
```

Then the TIMESTAMP() expression only needs to be evaluated against a subset of your data, instead of every row in the whole table.  In the example I show above, it'll only evaluate TIMESTAMP() if the Date matches the start or the end of the range of dates.  That might be useful if you the date range between Xdate and Ydate is very long and would match a lot of rows.  There's no need to run that function for all the dates in between.

I have not tested the above expression, so my apologies if I'm off by one or something, I think you should get the idea though.

Comment: Aha! Brilliant, this sped the query up a lot. Thank you :) 2 mins until I can accept the answer.

Comment: What is the implication of ELSE 1 in the case statement?

Comment: 1 is MySQL's "true" value.  If Date is neither the first or the last in the range, but somewhere in between, then it is certainly between the X and Y timestamps.

Comment: +1 from me. But I think it needs a minor correction for the case `'Xdate' = 'Ydate'` (it will only check the start time and not the end time for that case)

Comment: @ypercube, good point, but I could make an assumption that that case would be uncommon, and trying to cover it would complicate the query and the optimizer's job for little gain.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to rewrite the query be reversing the function to produce the dates and times from the X and Y timestamps only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Date, Time) >= ('Xdate', 'Xtime') 
  AND (Date, Time) <= ('Ydate', 'Ytime') ;
```

As explained by @BillKarwin in a comment, that will not benefit from an index. So, then rewrite it so the `(Date, Time)` index can be used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE 'Xdate' = 'Ydate'
          AND Date = 'Xdate' AND Time >= 'Xtime' AND Time <= 'Ytime'
   OR 'Xdate' < 'Ydate'
          AND ( Date = 'Xdate' AND Time >= 'Xtime'
             OR Date > 'Xdate' AND Date < 'Ydate'
             OR Date = 'Ydate' AND Time <= 'Ytime'
              ) ;
```

This way, no call at all on the `TIMESTAMP()` function will be needed.

Comment: Does the above statement consider times which go over midnight? At first glance it would seem like it does not?

Comment: Yes, it does. What do you mean with times over midnight? Times usually go from `'00:00:00'` to `'23:59.59'` Are you allowing negative times or more than `24:00:00` to that column?

Comment: Sorry, confused myself with the other statement I am writing, which does not span the full 24 hours. This query would work too then, thanks! +1